# On pressing Enter Key for processing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I'm working for both touch supported and keyboard supported. In my html i have written onclick function for touch. Where i can write for key pressing..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `keypress`, `keydown` and `keyup` events.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

```
$(document).keydown( function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
        //enter pressed
    }
});
```